# Serving NTFS partition on linux through ftp

Tags: linux, ftp, ntfs, chmod, chown

I'm using the default configuration for proftpd on Linux Mint with only the following directive changed:

```
# Use this to jail all users in their homes 
DefaultRoot         ~
```

I created a user `userftp` with the home directory as `/home/userftp`.
Next, I mounted an NTFS partition to `/home/userftp/files`.

I was able to ftp on to the home directory, but I cannot access the `files` directory. on the server the permissions shown for the `files` directory are '700'.

On running ls -l inside `/home/userftp`, I get the following:

```
drwx------ 1 wretrovian wretrovian 4096 2011-12-25 16:49 files
```

I assume the problem is that the owner of the files directory should be `userftp` and not `wretrovian`. However, running `sudo chmod 777 -R files` and `sudo chown -R userftp files` have no effect on the directory, the output still remains:

```
drwx------ 1 wretrovian wretrovian 4096 2011-12-25 16:49 files
```

I suppose I wont be able to apply those permissions to an NTFS system, but is their a way I can change the owner of the `files` directory? Or any other alternative would also be welcome..

Answer (score 2):

You should mount the NTFS partition with the option `uid=`. So something like this:

`mount -o uid=userftp /dev/<NTFS-partition> /home/userftp/files`.

See section `Mount options for NTFS` of the mount manpage: http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount